# ASP.NET Virtual application having same look as Root application

Tags: asp.net

I have a situation where I have several root applications that will reference the same virtual application.  The root applications are the "branded" front-ends that are fairly light, with the virtual application doing most of the work.

I was planning on having the virtual application use the Master File of the root application by referencing it with a "/" prefix, but have found out the hard way that this isn't allowed.

I have seen options such as compiling the Master Page as a .dll but I don't think I can apply this to me scenario because the Master Page will be different for every root application.

Does anybody have any ideas on what I can do as an alternative?  Is it possible to get creative with an inline Response.WriteFile call from the virtual to the root calling User Controls, or is there a downside to this?

Any ideas or assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around this problem is to not create the virtual application as an application in IIS.  By doing this, master page files from the root can still be used since there is only 1 app domain.  The downside is that you will have to merge your "bin" folders together under the root.

Comment: Yikes, that's a big downside.  The problem is that I could possibly have 100+ roots, and the virtual application could change frequently to add new features.  I don't want to have to have to recopy new .dll's to 100+ bins.

Comment: Are there many differences between your root files?  Maybe you could combine all of those sites into a single application, then make your app smart enough to server the correct files based on URL.

Comment: I don't think that's possible given the situation.  This was a classic ASP application that was using Server-Side includes to include headers and footers in the virtual from the root.  I was hoping that we could emulate the same functionality using Master Pages.

Comment: Instead of merging my virtual bin with my root bin, could I simply place the items in my virtual bin in the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a very clean way to do this other than what has been proposed by the other users.

Creative thinking:

**Cheap hack #1:** 
One way would be to use mklink on the server to create a directory junction. Cheap but you could easily script it and both folders would get updated at the same time.

**Cheap hack #2:** 
Have your master pages include an iframe to the shared vdir.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on #2?  It's not quite making sense to me how that would work.  TIA!